# htaccess need to rewrite subdirectory slug in urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The url i need to change:

https://www.mywebsite.com/MEMBERS/username/

I need members to change to model

https://www.mywebsite.com/MODEL/username/

this is my current code

RewriteRule ^(members/.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/model/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

however the page crashes when I use that code saying to many redirects.

can someone tell me what I need to fix.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out 
RedirectMatch "^/members/(.*)/(.*)" "https://www.mywebsite.com/model/$1/$2"